# Showing $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to show with a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that the function $$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{1 + x^2} $$ is continuous.

Here is what I did. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$ | f(x) - f(a) | = \bigg| \frac{1}{1 + x^2} - \frac{1}{1 + a^2} \bigg| = \frac{| a^2 - x^2 |}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)} \leq \frac{| x - a| (|a| + |x|)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}. $$ Now I think I need to use the trick that $$ \frac{|t|}{1 + t^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} $$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. If I do that here, I still get something complicated: $$ ... = \frac{|x - a| |a|}{ (1+x^2)(1+a^2)} + \frac{|x-a| |x|}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)} \leq \frac{|x-a|}{ 2 (1+x^2)} + \frac{|x-a|}{2(1+a^2)}. $$ I still got my RHS in terms of $x$, while I only want it in terms of $|x-a|$ and $a$ so than I can pick my $\delta$.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

$$\frac{|x-a|}{ 2 (1+x^2)} + \frac{|x-a|}{2(1+a^2)}\le \frac{|x-a|}{2} + \frac{|x-a|}{2}. $$

Or use

$$\frac{| x - a| (|a| + |x|)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\le \frac{2|x-a| \max\{|a|,|x|\}}{(1+a^2)(1+x^2)} \le 2|x-a|$$

and then choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I should pick $ \delta = \epsilon$ and I'm done right?

Comment: Yes. Note $\delta$ does not depend on $a$, so you showed indeed that $f$ is uniformly continuous. @Kamil

Answer (score 1):

In general, to show $f$ is continuous at $a$, it suffices to bound $|f(x)-f(a)|\le M|x-a|$ when $x$ closed to $a$,where $M$ is a constant depends on $a$.

For example, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$ | f(x) - f(a) | = \bigg| \frac{1}{1 + x^2} - \frac{1}{1 + a^2} \bigg| \le \frac{| x - a| (|a| + |x|)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\le | x - a| (|a| + |x|). $$

Hence given $\epsilon>0$, we let $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(2|a|+1)}\}$, then for all $|x-a|<\delta\le 1$, we will have $|x|\le |a|+1$, hence

$| f(x) - f(a) |\le (2|a|+1)|x-a|\le \frac{\epsilon}{2(2|a|+1)}(2|a|+1)=  \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$